# Locally editing a site with Amazon Web Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, local

I am completely new to AWS and have recently been handed two sites which are entirely run via this.

These sites now need quite a bit of development work so was wondering what the best way to go about doing this locally is?

I have found numerous ways to edit the site which then automatically pushes it up to the running instance, however because there is a lot of dev work involved, this is no good. I want to be able to test everything before it goes live.

Is the best way to create an instance running along side the live site and uploading a new development template to the stack for it to run from?

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not really clear what you need... Do you need to replicate an environment or do you want a continuous integration?

Comment: Sorry, I can understand why that's confusing now i've read it back.I would say probably replicate the site, then I can make changes without affecting the live/full version.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we works in two levels for testing:

First environment is a copy (using svn and DB replication) in a local machine, with the same OS.

When we need a final test to warranty everything is running as it should, we clone the entire servers (the main ones) with snapshots and create a new server for a limited period of time just for testing.

If your environment is not that big, you also could try an free tier server (if in first year) to constant test, and just update it as you want with new snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create an [AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) of the current site, then launch a new instance based upon it with the desired security levels.  That could then be your development system.

Once you've got it working on this new system you can switch over to it (after copying any necessary live data to it.)  Or you might create a new version of the AMI from this instance and launch the new production server from it.

One benefit of creating an ami of your latest version is that you have a way to recreate your server quickly if it gets hosed (assuming you also have backups of things like databases that get changed.)